# Required type is same as found type

Tags: java, types

I want to do this:

```
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>();
    Foo<String>.Bar fooBar = foo.new Bar();

    fooBar.doSomething("this works!");
```

But then the first 2 lines in a single line like:

```
Foo<String>.Bar fooBar2 = new Foo<>().new Bar();
fooBar2.doSomething("The above line gives: incompatible types. Required: Foo.Bar Found: Foo.Bar");
```

But the first line fails. I get:

> incompatible types.
>
> Required: Foo.Bar
>
> Found:    Foo.Bar

Why is that?

```
public class Foo<T> {


    public class Bar extends SomeOtherClass<T> {

        public void doSomething(T t) {

        }

    }

}
```

And the last class:

```
public class SomeOtherClass<T> {
}
```

Comment: A good start is read about type inference, see doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: bad error message. what compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some scenarios in which Java can't handle the type inference all that well (when one thinks it should).  This is one of those scenarios.

If you explicitly pass the type to the `new` invocation, it will compile:

```
Foo<String>.Bar fooBar2 = new Foo<String>().new Bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you tell java that you're using `Foo<string>` by declaring `foo` as a `Foo<string>`:

```
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>();
```

You need to clarify the type of  the template in `foo` better in the second example:

```
Foo<String>.Bar fooBar2 = (new Foo<String>()).new Bar();
```