# incompatible types; required and found. but the found is of required type

Tags: java, android

i am getting error "incompatible types. required: byte[]. found: java.lang.string

i have tried the solution from[incompatible types found and required are same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654656/required-type-is-same-as-found-type) , which stated that i must initialize the type. i initialized the byte[] but i am still getting that error

```
public static byte[] hash(char[] password, byte[] salt) {
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH);
    Arrays.fill(password, Character.MIN_VALUE);
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte [] hashedPass =  skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        return toHex(hashedPass);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("Error while hashing a password: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        spec.clearPassword();
    }
}

public static String toHex(byte[] Array){
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, Array);
    String hex = bi.toString(16);
    int paddingLength = (Array.length *2) - hex.length();
    if (paddingLength > 0){
        return String.format("%0" + paddingLength +"d", 0) + hex;
    } else {
        return hex;
    }
}
```

i am getting the error on line 7 :

```
return toHex(hashedPass);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `hash(char[] password, byte[] salt)` should return a `byte[]` and `return toHex(hashedPass)` returns String which is incompatible.

Alter the return type of method `toHex(hashedPass)` and return `byte[]` or
change,

From

```
return toHex(hashedPass);
```

To

```
return toHex(hashedPass).getBytes();
```